# Child component not re-rendering after parent component gets updated

Tags: reactjs

I have 1 parent(Container) and 2 (List, SelectedItem) child components, Initially I render all data to Container and send all data to list and first item as selectedItem to selected Item component. So ar so good

When a user clicks an item in the List component, it updates the selected item of the Parent through a function, the parent is able to update state, But it is not re-rendering selected item component.

List Component:

```
    import "./SelectedImage.css"

function ListSection({items, updateSelectedItem}) {
  return (
    <div className="list-section">
      <ul>
        {
          (items).map((item) => {
            return <li key={item.id} onClick={() => updateSelectedItem(item.id)}>{item.name}</li>
          })
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ListSection;
```

Container Component

```
    

    
import LeftSection from './LeftSection';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import RightSection from './RightSection ';
import SelectedItem from './SelectedItem';
import "./App.css";
import ListSection from './ListSection';
import { Component, useState } from 'react';

const products = [
  {id: 1, name: "Lime", size: ["large", "medium", "small"], category: "Juice", image: "lime-juice.jpg"},
  {id: 2, name: "Orange", size: ["large", "medium", "small"], category: "Juice", image: "orange-juice.jpg"},
  {id: 3, name: "Mango", size: ["large", "medium", "small"], category: "Juice", image: "mango-juice.jpg"},
]

function Container() {
  let [selectItem, setSelectItem] = useState(products[0]);

  function chooseSelectedItem(id) {
    let item = products.filter((value) => {
      console.log(value.id);
      return (value.id == id)
    })
    setSelectItem(item[0]);
    console.log(item[0]);
  }

  return (
    <div className="Container">
      <ListSection items={products} updateSelectedItem={chooseSelectedItem}/>
      <SelectedItem CurrentSelectedItem={selectItem}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Container;
```

SelectedItemComponent

```
import QuantityBar from "./QuantityBar";
import "./SelectedImage.css"
import { useState } from "react";

function SelectedItem({CurrentSelectedItem}) {
  let [item, setItem] = useState(CurrentSelectedItem);  

  return (
    <div className="selected-item">
      {/* <img src={item.image} className="selected-image" /> */}
      {item.name}
      {/* <QuantityBar itemCount={0} /> */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default SelectedItem;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're initializing the state using `useState` with the prop `CurrentSelectedItem`, any changes to `CurrentSelectedItem` won't be reflected in the state of the component.

You can use the `useEffect` hook to update the state of `SelectedItem` whenever `CurrentSelectedItem` changes:

```js
function SelectedItem({ CurrentSelectedItem }) {
  const [item, setItem] = useState(CurrentSelectedItem);

  useEffect(() => {
    setItem(CurrentSelectedItem);
  }, [CurrentSelectedItem]);

  ...
}
```

Or if `SelectedItem` is solely dependent on `CurrentSelectedItem`, you can remove the local state in `SelectedItem` and directly use `CurrentSelectedItem` as a prop, like

```js
function SelectedItem({ CurrentSelectedItem }) {
  return (
    <div className="selected-item">
      {/* <img src={CurrentSelectedItem.image} className="selected-image" /> */}
      {CurrentSelectedItem.name}
      {/* <QuantityBar itemCount={0} /> */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your code, it seems your `SelectedItem` component is being rerendered (as you could assess by placing a console.log statement in the component), but the selected item is being cached by your useState:

```
  let [item, setItem] = useState(CurrentSelectedItem);
```

The first argument of useState is the initial value; this value is only read on the initial render (i.e. when the component is mounted). Any rerenders afterwards will not update the value of `item`. Since you're reading the state's value in `{item.name}`, you'll always see the initial value. If you replace that line with `{CurrentSelectedItem.name}` (and maybe remove that useState), you will start seeing new value when an item is selected.